# How to save a large string into xml files in java?

Tags: java, xml

I loaded some large data as xml format into a string in my program (from mysql) and when I save this string into an out.xml, just about 500 record stored.
How do I save a large string or other data into a file in xml format or any other format?

Here is my Code :

```
    String xmlString = doExportIntoString();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
    Document document =factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(source);        
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    Result result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\xmlFile.xml"));
    Source s = new DOMSource(document);
    transformer.transform(s, result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a correct version of the code above:

```
BufferedWriter out;
try {
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
    out.write("aString");
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);    
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        try { out.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename"));
    out.write("aString");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: The code above is incorrect. If exception is thrown in write the writer won't be closed.

Comment: I don't think that is a relevant thing. I can also point out that you try catch in side your catch does have a finally in it also. What happe if you have an exception within your catch? Stick to the question, error catch is not the question here.

Comment: That's the java idiom. However, if exception happens when we are trying to close the writer we can't do anything about it.